# How to Get Selected Item values from ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have created a simple ListView with CheckBox for each item. 
I want the user to select some of the items.
How to get selected Items values by the user from this ListView and store them in for example in an  ArrayList ?

```
 ArrayList<String>  tablesName = new ArrayList<>();

    tablesName.add("one");
    tablesName.add("two");
    tablesName.add("three");
    tablesName.add("four");


    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, tablesName);

     var_tablesName_LV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
     var_tablesName_LV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    var_tablesName_LV.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


         }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a List like this globally :

```
 public static List<String> selectedValue = new ArrayList<String>() ;
```

then in OnItemClickListener write like this :

```
 var_tablesName_LV.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String clickedvalue =(String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i); 
         selectedValue.add(clickedvalue);

     }
```

Now all clicked value present in the ListArray , I Hope it helps !.

Comment: Thanks , problem fixed. One more thing, if the user unchecked the box how can i remove it from the array?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this below:-

```
      ThreeStrings your strings = (yourString)AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```